# AngularJS - orderBy multiple parameters of object and move null properties to the end of each parameter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I need to sort an array of objects, but the problem is if some property of the objects is `null`

Example

```
[   
    {
        "foo": 2,
        "bar": 1
    },
    {
        "foo": null,
        "bar": 1
    },
    {
        "foo": 1,
        "bar" : 2
    }
]
```

If I use orderBy:['foo', 'bar'] I get

```
[   
    {
        "foo": null,
        "bar": 1
    },
    {
        "foo": 1,
        "bar" : 2
    },
    {
        "foo": 2,
        "bar": 1
    }
]
```

But what I want to get is this

```
[   
    {
        "foo": 1,
        "bar" : 2
    },
    {
        "foo": null,
        "bar": 1
    },
    {
        "foo": 2,
        "bar": 1
    }
]
```

So in alphabetical order I want `null` to go after "z"

Comment: Should your resulting array be like `[{"foo": 1, ...}, {"foo": 2", ...}, {"foo": null, ...}]` if you want to have null after "z"?

Answer (score 0):

To change the regular sort behavior you would need to implement your own sorter:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <ul ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | myOrderBy:['foo', 'bar']">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.filter("myOrderBy", function () {
  return function (input, sortOrder) {
    return input.sort(function (a, b) {
      var order;
      for (var i = 0; i < sortOrder.length; i++) {
        order = sortOrder[i];
        if (a[order] !== b[order]) {
          break;
        }
      }

      // make null being ordered last
      if (a[order] === null && b[order] !== null) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (b[order] === null && a[order] !== null) {
        return -1;
      }

      // I am assuming you want to treat integers as strings
      if ("" + a[order] < "" + b[order]) {
        return -1;
      }
      if ("" + a[order] > "" + b[order]) {
        return 1;
      }

      // values are equal
      return 0;
    });
  };
});
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/cgav/pen/GpJoaB?editors=101

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto the answer by @ccg:

In order to handle nested properties in your sort (i.e. sort of ['foo.bar']) I modified his answer tot he following.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('app')
    .filter('nullsFirst', nullsFirst);

    function nullsFirst () {
        return function (input, sortOrder) {
            return input.sort(function (a, b) {
                var compA;
                var compB;
                for (var i = 0; i < sortOrder.length; i++) {
                    // check for nested properties
                    if (sortOrder[i].indexOf('.') !== -1) {
                        var order = sortOrder[i].split('.');

                        compA = a;
                        compB = b;

                        order.forEach(function (prop) {
                            if (compA != null) {
                                compA = compA[prop];
                            }
                            if (compB != null) {
                                compB = compB[prop];
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        compA = a[sortOrder[i]];
                        compB = b[sortOrder[i]];
                    }

                    if (compA !== compB) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // make null being ordered first
                if (compA == null && compB != null) {
                    return 1;
                }
                if (compB == null && compA != null) {
                    return -1;
                }

                // I am assuming you want to treat integers as strings
                if ('' + compA < '' + compB) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if ('' + compA > '' + compB) {
                    return 1;
                }

                // values are equal
                return 0;
            });
        }
    };
})();
```

This addition is not necessary for your particular problem but could provide a more complete solution to someone in the future.  Thanks to @ccg for the main portion.